# В переменную занести код с HTML тегами

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Пытаюсь так:

```
var hoverimg = "img-hover=<img src=http://site.ru/userfiles/shop/medium/" + val.icon

var resultat = '<li class="hover-img" title="" ' + hoverimg + '><img src="http://site.ru/userfiles/shop/32x32/' + val.icon + '">' + val.value + '</li>'

$(resultat).appendTo("#my_div")
```

получаю так:

```
<li class="hover-img" title="" img-hover="<img" src="http://site.ru/userfiles/shop/medium/418_kreplenie-gibkoe-gopro-jaws-flex.jpg"><img src="http://site.ru/userfiles/shop/32x32/418_kreplenie-gibkoe-gopro-jaws-flex.jpg">GoPro Крепление гибкое Jaws Flex Clamp</li>
```

Как видите, я получаю лишнюю *кавычку* `"` после `<img`. Из-за чего она там и как её убрать?

Comment: Тег внутри атрибута - очень плохой феншуй. Будут неожиданные проблемы в неожиданных местах. Что Вы пытаетесь сделать таким образом? Нельзя ли сохранить ссылку на изображение как     img-hover="http://site.ru/userfiles/shop/medium/418_kreplenie-gibkoe-gopro-jaws-flex.jpg" ?

Comment: Тег внутри атрибута надо html-кодировать: `&lt;` вместо `<` , `&quot;` вместо `"` и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поробуйте обернуть в кавычки и закрыть тег

```
var hoverimg = "img-hover=\"<img src=http://site.ru/userfiles/shop/medium/" + val.icon+">\""
```

Comment: По вашему примеру такой результат: `<li class="hover-img" title="res" img-hover="<img src=http://site.ru/userfiles/shop/medium/6415_gopro-hero4-black-edition-adventure.jpg">&gt;<img src="http://site.ru/userfiles/shop/32x32/6415_gopro-hero4-black-edition-adventure.jpg">GoPro Hero4 Black Edition Adventure</li>`

Comment: да, писал не проверил одну кавычку последнюю не туда вставил

Comment: да, теперь все гуд

Answer (score 0):

А вы в `hoverimg` значение `<img src=http://site.ru/userfiles/shop/medium/` оберните в одинарную кавычку и будет вам счастье.. Или наоборот. Все выражение в одинарные кавычки, а аттрибут в двойные.

Т.е. два варианта минимум

`var hoverimg = "img-hover='<img src=http://site.ru/userfiles/shop/medium/" +  val.icon + "'"`

или

`var hoverimg = 'img-hover="<img src=http://site.ru/userfiles/shop/medium/' + val.icon + '"'`

Comment: 1) результат : `<li class="hover-img" title="res" img-hover="<img src=http://site.ru/userfiles/shop/medium/" 6415_gopro-hero4-black-edition-adventure.jpg=""><img src="http://jazzmoto.ru/userfiles/shop/32x32/6415_gopro-hero4-black-edition-adventure.jpg">GoPro Hero4 Black Edition Adventure</li>` 
Второй результат: `<li class="hover-img" title="res" img-hover="<img src=http://site.ru/userfiles/shop/medium/" 418_kreplenie-gibkoe-gopro-jaws-flex.jpg=""><img src="http://site.ru/userfiles/shop/32x32/418_kreplenie-gibkoe-gopro-jaws-flex.jpg">GoPro Крепление гибкое Jaws Flex Clamp</li>`

Comment: Так надо сразу говорить что `val.icon` должна входит в аттрибут

Comment: надо задание внимательней читать=)

Comment: У вас это не написано. она у вас рядом просто пришлепана, как бедный родственник.. ну ок

Answer (score 0):

В значении html атрибута надо html-кодировать символы угловых скобок, кавычки, амперсент и некоторые другие. Поэтому понадобится ф-я замены:

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return String(str)
            .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
            .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
            .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

Удобнее держать html отдельно, и в нём использовать какие-то узнаваемые `%СТРОКИ%`, вместо которых потом подставлять рабочие значения. Такой базовый шаблонизатор. Здесь переизбыток таких замен, просто чтобы была понятнее суть идеи:

```
var url_icon = 'http://site.ru/userfiles/shop/32x32/%ICON%'
    .replace('%ICON%', val.icon);
var img_icon = '<img src="%URL_ICON%" alt="" title=""/>'
    .replace('%URL_ICON%', url_icon);

var url_hover = 'http://site.ru/userfiles/shop/medium/%ICON%'
    .replace('%ICON%', val.icon);
var img_hover = '<img src="%URL_HOVER%" alt="" title=""/>'
    .replace('%URL_HOVER%', url_hover);

var resultat = [
    '<li class="hover-img" title="" img-hover="%IMG_HOVER%">      ',
    '   %IMG_ICON%',
    '   %VALUE%                                               ',
    '</li>                                                    ',
].join("\n")
    .replace('%IMG_HOVER%', htmlEscape(img_hover))
    .replace('%IMG_ICON%', img_icon)
    .replace('%VALUE%', val.value)
;

$(resultat).appendTo("#my_div")
```

**Получается** что-то вроде:

```
<li class="hover-img" title="" img-hover="&lt;img src=&quot;http://site.ru/userfiles/shop/medium/icon.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; title=&quot;&quot;/&gt;">    
    <img src="http://site.ru/userfiles/shop/32x32/icon.jpg" alt="" title=""/>
    value here                                                
</li>
```

[Фиддл](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/qpfwkfLw/).